# Any tips on improving this postgres function that creates alias and then returns it as json. To translate column headers to different language

Tags: json, postgresql, function, sql-injection

Given a table, and then another 'meta data' table that contains the translations. The function looks up the translation and then builds an alias statement. Also is it injection safe?

https://dbfiddle.uk/JQ6AnBVx

Comment: What is your tech stack? This should be handled by the front end using standard internationalization (i18n) libraries. I feel like you're reinventing the wheel and opening yourself up to security issues. You should be able to search for "i18n" and your programming language to find info on managing multiple languages in your application.

Answer (score 0):

This has SQL injections in several areas - whether they are exploitable or not will depend on what information can be passed through a trust boundary (passed in be an untrusted user / program).

For instance in your `translate_column` function all the parameters (except for the language ID) can be used for SQL injection.  If any of those can (or in the future may) come from untrusted sources this is vulnerable.

Similarly, if your `alias_text` or `translated_column` can be controlled by an untrusted user, the `f_get_table_with_alias` is vulnerable.  This includes allowing unvalidated data being inserted into your test tables.

There are two options to do this safely - ideally you should use both:

- When your users create the names used for tables (or any DB objects) you may should limit the names to use a "safe" set of characters (alphanumeric & dashes, underscores...)
- You should enquote the table names / column names - adding double quotes around the objects. If you do this, you need to be careful to validate there are no quotes in the name, and error out or escape the quotes. You also need to be aware that adding quotes will make the name case sensitive.